# Creating if else statement in Matlab for choosing the correct matrix

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix

I am new to matlab (and programing in general) and I am trying to Create a if else statement that would allow me to choose the proper Rotational matrix, but when my code runs, causes an error when I input the choice. I added my screenshots my code [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tps3i.png) and of the command window error I obtain [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yasku.png). Thank you in advance.

code

```
%% Creating a matrix Rot reprensenting the rotatinal transformation that is applied. 

theta = input('Input the value of angle: ');

% Chose the direction 

Dir = input('Input around which axis the rotation occurs (x,y or z): '); % this creates an error 

if Dir == 'x'
    
    Rot = [1 0 0;0 cosd(theta) -sind(theta);0 sind(theta) cos(theta)];
    
elseif Dir == 'y'
    
    Rot = [cosd(theta) 0 sind(theta);0 1 0;0 -sind(theta) cos(theta)];
    
elseif Dir == 'Z'
    
     Rot = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0;0 sind(theta) cos(theta);0 0 1];
    
else 
    disp('Not an axis.')
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tps3i.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yasku.png)

Comment: Please don't post code as image. Provide a [mcve] in your question. Try `'x'` instead of `x`

Comment: oh sorry I will modify it, and I already tried using x instead and it ended with the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Parsing Inputs as Strings

The only thing I think needs to be changed is how this `input()` is parsed. The axis of rotation, `Dir` can be parsed as a string, `'s'` allowing it to be used in the following if conditions. The `'s'` can be indicated by the second input argument into `input()` → `input('Please enter something','s')`.

Alternatively as **Thomas** suggested using the string notation for input indicated by the quotes also works `'x'`, `'y'` or `'z'` (not sure if they're any discrepancies between MATLAB versions).

### Code Snippet:

```
Dir = input('Input around which axis the rotation occurs (x,y,z): ','s');
```

---

### Method 1: Using If-Else Statements

```
%% Creating a matrix Rot reprensenting the rotatinal transformation that is applied. 
theta = input('Input the value of angle: ');

% Chose the direction 
Dir = input('Input around which axis the rotation occurs (x,y or z): ', 's'); % this creates an error 

if Dir == 'x'  
    Rot = [1 0 0;0 cosd(theta) -sind(theta);0 sind(theta) cos(theta)];
    
elseif Dir == 'y'
    Rot = [cosd(theta) 0 sind(theta);0 1 0;0 -sind(theta) cos(theta)];
    
elseif Dir == 'z'
     Rot = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0;0 sind(theta) cos(theta);0 0 1];
else 
    disp('Not an axis.')

end
```

---

### Method 2: Using a Switch Case

```
theta = input('Input the value of angle: ');
Dir = input('Input around which axis the rotation occurs (x,y,z): ','s');


switch Dir
    case "x"
        disp('x-case');
        Rot = [1 0 0;0 cosd(theta) -sind(theta);0 sind(theta) cos(theta)];

    case "y"
        disp('y-case');
        Rot = [cosd(theta) 0 sind(theta);0 1 0;0 -sind(theta) cos(theta)];

    case "z"
        disp('z-case');
        Rot = [cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0;0 sind(theta) cos(theta);0 0 1];

    otherwise
        disp('Not a valid axis');           
end

%Continue code below the corresponding Rot will be selected%
```

Comment: okay adding simply the 's' fixed it thank you, but now if i wanted to use your method two example and  define my x-case, for example, should I do it before the if or switch statement or after it? Logically I think I should do it before since the way I understand it is that your code would only display case x, right?

Comment: If you wanted to use the switch statement the `Rot`, corresponding rotation matrices can be put under each `disp()` call respectively. I'll add that in.